# Fullcalendar Events not displaying even if events end time exist

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

This is very confusing。。why event on 2017-09-02 before 9AM doesn't show while event after 9AM is effictive 。 is there any options can control this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
            },
            defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'test11111',
                    start: '2017-09-01T16:00:00',
                    end: '2017-09-02T09:00:00'
                },
                {
                    title: 'test22222',
                    start: '2017-09-01T16:00:00',
                    end: '2017-09-02T08:00:00'
                },
            ],
            timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)',
            displayEventEnd: {
                    month: true,
                    default: true
            }
        });
```

[how can i make 2017-09-02 display in view?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZmUg.png)

Comment: 12 hours clock?

Comment: perhaps not .i have set   timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)'   it's  24-hour clock

Comment: @Finiox  
perhaps not .i have set timeFormat: 'HH(:mm)' it's 24-hour clock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `nextDayThreshold`.  By default, it is set to 9am, and that means that any event ending before that will not be rendered on that day.

In your case you have an event ending at 8am, so you need a `nextDayThreshold` of 8am or earlier if you want that even to show up on that day:

```
nextDayThreshold: '08:00:00'
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/j8ncqy0z/).

[Fullcalendar nextDayThreshold docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/)